# Can I use my Ubuntu hdd on other computers?

Tags: hard-drive

I have been running Ubuntu for a bit now. Today my motherboard died and I want to know if I can plug my hdd to another computer, would it boot and run Ubuntu normally. Heard can't do that with windows.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: Yes, Ubuntu usually deals with different hardware really well and it just works.  Make sure that the drive is compatible with the new system, and that you set the boot option to boot from it.

Answer (score 1):

**yes you can and its really possible**.

I did it myself couple of times by changing my laptops from one model to another but swapping my harddisk. 
But be ready to get surprises as well, it would be a good idea to have a backup but if you don't have one there is no issue. your data won't be lost, you can always use a live CD and copy the data.

you may need to install a couple of softwares and recompile kernel, if the H/W is drastically changed.